# Is there any meaning behind so many tags in html?

Tags: html

So I am now learning html, and I was just wondering why tags such as **cite** even exist. When I open a website as a user, I still see the text as *italic* when the code is written as **cite**.

I found that the tags are useful when it comes to screen readers, so basically for users that have problems with their vision.

Are there any more reasons for these tags? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `cite` is some kind of a [semantic tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html). The rendering, i.e. how you see it, is up to the css that is pplied to the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are small snippets of HTML coding that tell engines how to properly “read” your content. In fact, you can vastly improve search engine visibility by adding SEO tags in HTML.

When a search engine’s crawler comes across your content, it takes a look at the HTML tags of the site. This information helps engines like Google determine what your content is about and how to categorize the material.

Some of them also improve how visitors view your content in those search engines. And this is in addition to how social media uses content tags to show your articles.

In the end, it’s HTML tags for **SEO** that will affect how your website performs on the Internet. Without these tags, you’re far less likely to really connect with an audience.

About `cite` tag: The  tag defines the title of a creative work (e.g. a book, a poem, a song, a movie, a painting, a sculpture, etc.). Note: A person's name is not the title of a work. The text in the  element usually renders in italic.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding the `cite` tag, according to MDN:

> The  HTML element is used to describe a reference to a cited
> creative work, and must include the title of that work. The reference
> may be in an abbreviated form according to context-appropriate
> conventions related to citation metadata.

This enables you to manage all the css applied to quotes easily, were that to be your use case (if you happened to have a lot of quotes on a site). The italics you have observed are part of that css, or rather the default css applied by the browser.

## In the broader spectrum

Oftentimes you will run into tags that as of today are not in use anymore. There's different industry standards for different time periods.

All of the tags exist, because there was a reason for web browsers to have a specific way of reading a piece of content.

For example centering a div used to be an almost legendary task that was achievable using multiple methods, all of which had different advantages and disadvantages. However, nowdays it's customary to use the flexbox.

Bottom line is its a way for web browsers and search engines to read and interpret the content you're providing

Answer (score 0):

Tags such as   and  are used for text decoration nothing else you can also change text fonts and styles by using CSS.